Databricks connection to Oracle Cloud: Listener refused the connection with the following error
I'm getting really frustrated with this error as "Listener refused the connection with the following error:". I don't really know which caused this error, I don't even have the full error shown, it's just one line like this:enter image description here
What I have tried to do:

I added the specific ojdbc8.jar, which is the version that is compatible with the current version of Databricks, and the wallet connection zip file as:

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName('SparkContent') \
    .config('spark.driver.memory', '15g') \
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', 'dbfs:/FileStore/jars/d10772cb_3696_4274_b38c_ee49d540d7ce-ojdbc8.jar') \
    .config('spark.executor.extraClassPath', 'dbfs:/FileStore/jars/d10772cb_3696_4274_b38c_ee49d540d7ce-ojdbc8.jar') \
    .config('spark.net.wallet_location', 'dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/triethoangminh555@gmail.com/Wallet_PRFFIGRTZ8WW08IK.zip') \
    .getOrCreate()


For the JDBC connection, I have tried with:

connection_url  = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcps://{host_name}:1522/{service_name}'

or the full service name version
connection_url  = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=my_host_goes_here)(connect_data=(service_name=ge1e779a6634c11_prffigrtz8ww08ik_high.adb.oraclecloud.com)))'


and I still gets the error as my connection is refused, I'm pretty sure that I'm connecting with the admin account, and write or update privileges are allowed as I have checked for this one
Some advices that I have found on Oracle Support page is through increasing the numbers
of PROCESSING in my Oracle Cloud database, but I'm not authenticated to do so. What is really causing this problem, this is my last step on my pipeline already :(

If the listener is refusing the connection then it's not getting as far as checking the credentials or privileges, and it implies the host name and port are correct. Obviously the full error would be helpful... It could be ORA-12514 - are you sure that service name it right? What does lsnrctl services show? Or maybe ORA-12516 if sqlnet.ora isn't set up for TCPS (I think), or maybe you have an ACL blocking it. It's hard to guess - service name is the easy one to fix though.

I mean, I don't really know the full error, I couldn't see it, this is the screen shot that I can have, I have unlist the error, but what it does is that pointing directly to my code. I have edited my question with the full-screen shot, it is exactly what I have had

1 more detail is that. I'm not pretty sure which one is exactly the matched service name. I saw there's 2 part. 1 with instancename_high, or medium, low, it depends. And another one is the one that I copied directly from the connection string, which was different as well

I'm not sure what you mean. Are you using service names you got from lsnrctl services? Anyway... maybe try connecting with the same connection string from the same client machine, using something that will show the full error, like SQL*Plus or SQLcl or SQL Developer.

Try with the connection_url:
jdbc:oracle:thin:/@instancename_high?TNS_ADMIN=PATH_TO_THE_WALLET

